# How to make node.js localhost public

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running node.js on port 3000 right now so it only loads on localhost:3000 on my computer. But I would like to test it on multiple computers. How could I do this?

Here is the code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  console.log(socket.id)
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: Connect those multiple computers in a network (e.g. LAN), enter the address (e.g. IP) and port of the server in any computer's browsers. Done. This has nothing to do with javascript or nodejs.

Comment: can you please give a example

Comment: No, I can't give an example, there is no code or anything. You just need to learn about networking, and if you need additional configuration it depends a lot on your setup (network topology, operating systems, internet connection, number of computers, what router you are using...)

Comment: @jujumumu fully agree with Bergi, but also simple thing that you need, is to know what your internal ip. Then you will able to connect to your node server with this host + port. Example: to get your host on linux you can use this command - ifconfig en0, it's will show something like inet 192.168.31.70 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.31.255, first ip is you internal address. Then just call http://your_ip:port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour is to listen on all available network interfaces, not just localhost, so the short answer is **do nothing**.

Any computer that can issue a network request to your computer can access the server by making an HTTP report to port 3000 on any IP address your computer has.

Most computers the development work is performed on do not have an ip address on the public Internet. So for computers outside your local network to access the service, you would need to configure your Internet router to forward requests to some port it has available to port 3000 on your LAN IP address.